# Please make [google-spreadsheet-charts] a synonym of [google-sheets-charts]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The official (current) name of the product is "Google Sheets", so tags about it and its functionality should reflect that.

Please make [google-spreadsheet-charts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet-charts) a synonym of [google-sheets-charts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-charts).

Answer (score 1):

The tags have been merged and synonymized.