# Can we rename [google-documents] and [google-presentations]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags

Ref: [Can we rename [google-spreadsheets] and [google-spreadsheets-query]?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/can-we-rename-google-spreadsheets-and-google-spreadsheets-query)

and: [Please make [google-spreadsheet-charts] a synonym of [google-sheets-charts]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/please-make-google-spreadsheet-charts-a-synonym-of-google-sheets-charts)

Please rename:

[google-documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-documents) > [google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs), and
[google-presentations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-presentations) > [google-slides](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-slides)

The above would bring us up to date (after more than five years). (And presumably has SEO implications.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both tags have been merged and synonymized.